# Getting property privacy with Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to get the current privacy status for a determine user's property. I'm doing nothing fancy, I just need to know how the property is configured so I can take decisions. This is my code:

```
      SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {   
           using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2010dev:3767"))
            { 
                context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                psm = ProfileSubtypeManager.Get(context);
                upm = new UserProfileManager(context, false);
                UserProfile user = upm.GetUserProfile(false);
                Privacy privacy = user["SPS-Skills"].Privacy;
            }
        });
```

I obtain this message: Access Denied: You may inly retrieve your own profile's privacy setting, unless you are an administrator.

Any clue?

Comment: When you use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges, you are effectively running code as your IIS AppPool user.  Is that user a site collection admin on the site?

Comment: Nop, it's MySite. I'm trying to get one colleague privacy policy for showing or hidding the property. I just have one user in my code example for simplicity.

Comment: If yuo're hitting mysite, consider not running with elevated privs..

Comment: I know, Really I do. But how can I get then the property privacy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**strange!!!** its should be work your code. don't know why its not running?

you should try this

```
   try
        {
            SPUser AdminUser = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
            var superToken = AdminUser.UserToken;
            HttpContext con = HttpContext.Current;
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, superToken))
                {
                    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                    HttpContext.Current = null;
                    UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(context, false);
                    \\get useprofile code
                 }  
             });
           HttpContext.Current = con;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Hops this helps.

Comment: That totally works! And now I own you my first born. Thanks a lot!